# Java check if static value true in while

Tags: java

I am creating in the console a program that adds new students but i wish to check if the max capacity of students is reached or not.

I am learning Java on my own so sorry if my code is not as it should be.
I would appreciate your feedback if you have suggestions.

Main

```
   boolean abort = false;
    boolean unlocked = false;
    //Student[] students = new Student[School.MAX_studentEntered];
    ArrayList<Student> students= new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!abort){ //for as long as the value is not abort the loop will run
        System.out.println("Unlock Admin(1) New Student(2) Show Students(3) Statistics (4) ");
        System.out.print("Input: ");
        int input = option.nextInt();
        
       switch (input){

            case 0:{
                abort = true;
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                System.out.println("Admin");
                unlocked = true;
                break;
            }
```

//problem is case 2

```
 case 2: {
                System.out.println("Create a student");

                  int time = 0;

                  while (time<=School.MAX_studentEntered) {

                    Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.print("Name: ");
                    String name = st.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Age: ");
                    int age = st.nextInt();
                    Student student = new Student();
                    student.setName(name);
                    student.setAge(age);
                    students.add(student);
                    time++;

                      if(unlocked){
                            System.out.print("Create another student? (yes/no): ");
                            Scanner ans= new Scanner(System.in);
                            String answer = ans.nextLine();
                            if (!answer.equals("yes")) {
                                break;
                                }
                            else {
                                if(time>School.MAX_studentEntered){
                                    System.out.println("You have reached the max capacity!");
                                    break;
                                }
                                else {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                      }
                      if(time>School.MAX_studentEntered){
                          System.out.println("You have reached the max capacity!");
                          break;
                      }
                      else {
                            break;
                      }
                }
                break;

            }
```

Class Student

```
public class Student {

String name;
int age;


public Student(){
    School.studentEntered++;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;

}
public void setAge(int age){ //void - save the value
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName(){ //return - show the value
    return name;
}
public int getAge(){
    return age;
}
```

}

School Class

```
 public class School {

  static int studentEntered = 0;
  static final int MAX_studentEntered=3;
  public School(){
// it is automaticlly created when the class is created
// it does not need a void or return
    studentEntered++;
}
```

}

I expect the program to stop adding new students in the arrayList if the capacity (MAX_studentEntered) is reached and to print an error after the break

Comment: not sure what the initial value of unlock here `if(unlocked)` and 
```if(time>School.MAX_studentEntered){
                          System.out.println("You have reached the max capacity!");
                          break;
                      }
                      else {
                            break;
                      }```
will make the loop break despite if you reach the limit or not

Comment: break here mean break from the inner most loop which is your while loop in case if you missed this

Comment: the issue with @AltinMag. 
```  if (time > School.MAX_studentEntered) {
                            System.out.println("You have reached the max capacity!");
                            break;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }```
as mentioned earlier this part will make the loop end so either remove the else part or replace the break in that else with continue
but the best thing that you learn how to debug based on your IDE you use look for how to add break point

Comment: then from your IDE choose debug it will run the program till you reach the breakpoint then use step over which make you run the program line by line so you know how it work